# finding all euler cycles in undirected graph

Tags: c++, graph

I want to find all euler cycles in a undirected graph. The representation of the graph is adjacency list. I have a function that finds only one cycle. How to improve it to find all cycles ?

```
void DFSEuler(int v, list<int> L[])
{
while(!L[v].empty())
{
    int x = L[v].front();
    L[v].pop_front();
    for(list<int>::iterator i =L[x].begin(); i != L[x].end(); i++)
        if((*i) == v)
        {
            L[x].erase(i); break;
        }
        DFSEuler(x, L);
}
q.push_front(v);

}
```

Graph is connected and all vertex degree are even.

Comment: There can be exponentially many Euler cycles in a given graph. Are you sure that you really want to list all of them?

Comment: I need too measure time of finding all of them